# Error: installing rails Error: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error when trying to install Rails:

```
    Z:\AlexL\My Documents\rails>gem install rails
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

Z:\AlexL\My Documents\rails>gem install rails -include-dependencies
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
    bad URI(is not URI?): ?gems=ûinclude-dependencies

Z:\AlexL\My Documents\rails>rails
'rails' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My Ruby version is:

**ruby 1.9.3p484**

how can I fix this? I'm on windows bytheway.

Comment: Please, paste the full stack trace

Answer (score 1):

The error message you got clearly states:

> Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
>   from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
>   at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

So, my advise would be you to download the DevKit and follow the instructions.

Comment: Then update your `PATH` environment variable for ruby to find the binaries.

Comment: [how to update PATH variable in windows](https://www.google.es/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=30TbVOirLc6p8wf_rIGYBg&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=how+to+update+PATH+variable+in+windows).